# python beautifulsoup tag that contains multiple full text lines not easily found in a generalisable way

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, parent-child

There are multiple questions open and answered regarding using beautiful soup to extract text from a line however there are no solutions I can find to obtain correct text such as:

```
<div>
     <div>
     <span>2</span>
     <span>bananas</span></div>

     <div>
     <span>3</span>
     <span>oranges</span></div>
</div>
```

that are generalised to produce output:

```
2 bananas
3 oranges
```

where the parent can be found to be `<div>` and the requirement to specify  as part of the findall is not required.

Interestingly, html2text can produce the perfect output for such types of files (without the tag), but beautifulsoup doesn't seem to be able to do it correctly at all. beautifulsoup will produce output with each word on a line, or many solutions online will produce a concatenation with spaces between word using `' '.join(t.strip() for t in visible_text)`

Its the nesting of visible text in multiple lower levels that seems to cause the issue for beautiful soup. `<a>` inside the `<div>` also causes the same issues.

I tried this:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(myHtmlFile, 'html.parser')
    groupedElements = soup.findAll(['ul','ol','td','p','li', 'br','div']) 
    for internalElements in groupedElements:
        for listElement in internalElements:
            wantedText = listElement.text
        wantedTag = inernalElements.parent
```

so we want the **tag** containing **each individual full text line** to be preserved, not a tag with say `2\nbananas\n3\oranges` or `2 bananas 3 orange`.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting `div` is a problem because it will select both the top-level div and the nested divs. So in my code below I use `soup.select()` to just get the nested divs. Although this won't work correctly if the actual hierarchy is `<div><div><div>`. You would be best off using a class that selects just the nested divs.

```
divs = soup.select('div > div') # find div that's a direct child of another div
for div in divs:
    spans = div.findall('span')
    line = ' '.join(span.text for span in spans)
    print(line)
```

Comparing BS with `html2text` is somewhat unfair. BS is a general HTML/XML parser, the logic of what to do with the data is up to the application. `html2text` is a rendering engine, like a simple browser, so it formats the output in a way that mirrors the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> soup.find_all(name=True, string=True)
[<span>2</span>, <span>bananas</span>, <span>3</span>, <span>oranges</span>]
```

The `parent` will be duplicated though - so you can filter those:

```
>>> for tag in dict.fromkeys(tag.parent for tag in soup.find_all(name=True, string=True)):
...     tag.get_text(separator=' ', strip=True)
'2 bananas'
'3 oranges'
```